# Can Observium analyze network traffic?

Tags: monitoring, network-monitoring, observium

I'm running a observium server analyzing my office devices, but I'd like to know if there's a way for observium to analyze the network traffic.

English is not my main language, so I don't know *how* to search this, nor if its possible. I'd like to see *which* ports are being used.

Example:

```
==Network==
HTTP: 128kb
SMTP: 25kb
FTP:  310Kb
```

Or something alike... Is it ***even*** called like that? Else, what's its name?

And, more importantly, can I monitor that with observium? If not, which tool can I use?

Thank you all beforehand, please excuse my errors/lack of clarity.

Comment: Nevermind, I kept on investigating and found out it's name was _Netflow_, and Observium doesn't support it.

https://www.mail-archive.com/observium@observium.org/msg04530.html

Also, I think wireshark might do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Just found the following.
 Observium has support for nfsen, which could collect flows: http://www.observium.org/wiki/Configuration_Options#NfSen

Reference: http://postman.memetic.org/pipermail/observium/2013-December/004931.html

Comment: Hi and welcome of serverfault. Please provide more detailed answer instead of just giving links : They can become dead.